# How do I filter a dataframe using boolean mask

Tags: pandas, filter, mask

The name of the dataframe variable is df

```
df.dtypes
```

when run give this output :

```
tx_price                int64

beds                    int64

baths                   int64

lot_size                int64

property_type          object

exterior_walls         object

roof                   object

basement              float64

restaurants             int64

groceries               int64

nightlife               int64
```

how do I filter df.dtypes using boolean mask such that I get the following  output?

```
property_type     object

exterior_walls    object

roof              object

dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

Could use a `lambda` inside `.loc`

```
df.dtypes.loc[lambda x: x == object]
```